# How do I get ghci to see packages I installed from cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

I've installed the such-and-such a package using cabal, and I can build a program that depends on it using `cabal build`. But when I load the same program in ghci, ghci complains that it "Could not find module `such-and-such'".

I'm surprised this doesn't "just work." How do I tell ghci where to find the packages I've installed with cabal?

Here's my setup: I'm using GHC 6.10.4 on Mac OS X 10.6.3, cabal-install version 0.6.2 using version 1.6.0.3 of the Cabal library.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need

```
ghci -package such-and-such
```

And to double-check that `such-and-such` is truly visible to GHC, run `ghc-pkg list | grep such-and-such`.

Comment: I'm preferring this answer since I'd rather not clutter up the global package namespace with exposed packages.

Bonus round: *In* ghci, how do I dynamically add a package?

Comment: `:set -package haskell-src-meta` works. I think you can set any `ghci`/`ghc` flag with `:set`. Like `:set -XTemplateHaskell`.

Answer (score 15):

`ghc-pkg list` on the command line will tell you what your installed packages are. The installed package might be hidden, in which case you can reveal it with `ghc-pkg expose {pkg-id}`.

Comment: Here is what that outputs:

    bash-3.2$ ghc-pkg list lrucache
    /opt/local/lib/ghc-6.10.4/./package.conf:
    /Users/dominic/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-6.10.4/package.conf:
        lrucache-1.0

How do I go from that, to where the package *is*? And then do I use `ghci -i`?

Comment: Yes! `ghc-pkg register such-and-such` is indeed the required magic. Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to change your cabal prefs to do global registers. Change ~/.cabal/config to say `user-install: False`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `cabal repl` to ask cabal to open the GHCi interpreter with all the right settings for your project.